# disable submit button before and after the button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, submit

I was trying to make this example here work, but unable [hide submit button](http://jsfiddle.net/Hudt8/21/)

This is another example of the same type: [hide submit till checkbox is checked](http://jsfiddle.net/XZyjw/63/)
The weird thing is I tried the above demo on my MS expression web and previewed it in Chrome, but didn't work. The whole thing I want is to hide the submit button till a user fill in all blanks and agree to service terms then the button shows up. And this is the first part.

The second part is that I want to hide the submit button after the submit button is clicked... like this example: [demo: hide button after submit](http://jsfiddle.net/sCgZ9/9/), but also this one doesn't work when I try it on my own...

is it possible to combine both codes so it works in a way that I can hide the submit button till required fields are filled and hide it again if the form  is submitted...

your help is much appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr><td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="agree" id="agree">I agree Terms and Conditions</td></tr>
        <tr><td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" style="display:none" value="submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#agree').change(function() {
        $('#submit').hide();
        if(this.checked){
            $('#submit').show();   
        }
    });
    $('#submit').on('click', function(){
        $('#submit').hide();
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Fccj/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it, but it seems JavaScript for some reason doesn't work for me... I still don't know why... any idea!! 
as I mentioned before, both demos on my original question didn't work mainly because of the JavaScript.... there must be something incorrect...

Comment: @MihaiIorga, it works on Fiddle, but it doesn't work on my side... this is the main issue..

Comment: I mean live, and not an image. How can I debug an image?

Comment: @MihaiIorga, sorry about that. Here is a live example: http://www.forexmegacashback.com/test.html

Comment: Copy paste the code again, I've modified. It seems there was an unicode character there.

Comment: @MihaiIorga, Thanks a lot. now it works fine. It is weird though I don't understand what changes took place so it worked!! Thanks again...